# Automating Azure VIP Swap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app hosted as an Azure web role.  I want to do something that seems like it should be pretty standard: **I want to create a function that I can call that initiates a VIP swap and raises and event (or calls a callback) when the VIP Swap operation is done.**

Just to add some context to the situation: My website implements a workflow that takes about an hour (or less) to complete. If I want to release a new version of the website code, it's convenient (i.e. much less "backward compatibility" code to write) to first let all of the current users complete the workflow so that the new code doesn't need to deal with data created by the previous version of the code. So a management function in my website would first poke a value into the database that disables new workflows; it would then wait until all current workflows are done; it would then call the "VIP Swap" routine; finally, when the VIP Swap routine signals its completion, it would poke the database value to re-enable new workflows.

I found the Microsoft documentation for how to programmatically initiate a VIP swap here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460814.aspx

The procedure involves POSTing to a magic URL and including some headers in the POST, then periodically performing a GET to a magic URL and checking the response code.

The more I think about this, the more non-trivial it seems. In addition to the basic complexities of wiring up a background timer and completion notification, I don't know what complexities, if any, I might run into trying to do this stuff in the IIS environment. Can I even perform HTTP operations on a background thread?  For that matter, will I run into complications just trying to use any of the half dozen or so different "do things in the background" mechanisms baked into .NET?

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.  In particular, **I'd be ecstatic if someone could point me at a ready-to-go implementation of this function!**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find an easy solution to this as the fabric controller is setup to do some very fancy things without your involvement. Running hour-long workflows on a cloud computing environment, where an instance can be pulled out from underneath you, (with a maximum of 5 minutes from the OnStopping event being called to clean up) requires that you do other work anyway to make sure that all of your tasks complete.

The simple question is "What do you do if an instance goes down when workflows are still running?" Do you restart them or are they lost? If they get lost then you don't care anyway, so killing workflows for an upgrade are equally unimportant. If you re-start them then use that same mechanism to decide whether or not a node is due to be shut down, and distribute the jobs accordingly. This pattern is eerily similar to the [Hadoop JobTracker](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/JobTracker). Don't just run the workflows on any 'ol instance. Submit them to a (job tracker) service that decides what to do. The (job tracker) service can then use the service management API to scale up as many instances as you need running the version that you want, run workflows on the appropriate node, and shut them down when they are no longer needed or are outdated.

Unfortunately this may not be the simple solution that you are looking for, but something in your architecture needs to change, rather than trying to force PaaS to fit with your current approach. Decompose your workloads, create loosely coupled services, design for failure, and a few other cloud/distributed computing practices need to be considered. There is a reason why Hadoop is built the way that it is — and it has a reputation for being able to get work done on a bunch of somewhat unreliable commodity hardware.

Comment: I'm confused. (I'm also new to this whole web thing.) As I understand, if I'm running multiple instances of my server and one instance goes down then users simply get routed to another instance. As long as at least one instance is running, and all instances see a consistent view of the database that contains work-in-progress, why do I care? And what does any of this have to do with my original question?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand the confusion... A "workflow" (as referenced in the OP) is NOT a 1-hour long computational process. My "workflow" is: User logs in; User completes online survey, which consists of multiple GETs and POSTs; User receives survey results.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. I realise now that your problem is that you do retain state between requests, but those requests have to run on the same version of the app until the user is done.